# How to Continue Test on failure

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have a short Selenium IDE test that just checks the titles of some web pages, 4 links that's it.

And in selenium IDE if one of the title checks fails it will continue, and alert in the log about the failure.  Where as in `Selenium-side-runner` the test just fails and stops the moment it hit the failure and does not continue.  Is there an `argument` I can pass so that the execution continues even after failure?

I tried looking up the argument, but couldn't find any info.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, ( read how to properly form a question ) I would like to help you, but there is nothing what I look at, would you mind to show us some code / add some pictures to show us what have you tried ?

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/18349435/9559884>  try to look at this

Comment: please provide a sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Asserts?
Something like this:

```
driver.get(url1)
AssertEquals (webElement1.title, "expected title 1")
driver.get(url2)
AssertEquals (webElement2.title, "expected title 2")
```

You could do this a couple of ways:
By eliminationg the asserts, tracking your checks and checking at the end of the test for errors:

```
errors = 0; 
driver.get(url1)
if (webElement1.title != "expected title 1") { errors++;}
driver.get(url2)
if(webElement2.title != "expected title 2")  { errors++;}
Assert.equals (errors, 0)
```

of you could use soft assertions. Which depending on the framework you're using, the usage differs.
One such usage: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-writing-assertions-with-assertj/